# C++ dynamic datatype with persistent location

Tags: c++, pointers, dynamic, types

The question might sound a bit ridiculus, but maybe it's possible.

First some information:
I'm creating a chunk management system for a voxel terrain engine.
Each chunk has to be able to access each of its 6 neighbour chunks. So every chunk contains a pointer to his 6 neighbours. That's the reason why the memory location of a chunk cannot change. In the moment my setup looks like this:

```
ChunkMap chunks;                // unordered_map of chunks
ChunkSet createdChunks;         // set of pointers to unordered_map entries
ChunkSet generatedChunks;       // set of pointers to unordered_map entries
vector<Chunk*> renderedChunks;
```

Since an unordered_map changes the location of its entrys this leads to errors because the pointers to the chunk neighbours are accessing the wrong location.

**Summary:**
The datatype should

- have a persistent memory adress
- support adding and removing an unknown count of entries
- be as efficient as possible

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am very surprised, that you even thought about using `std::` container for such task. You need a specialized, performance-oriented data structure here. There is nothing in `std::`, that you could use for such task. And even if it was, you would still get better performance with custom, well-designed, carefully-implemented solution. But that's just my opinion **(\*)**.

**(\*)** *I'm currently working on multi-platform rendering engine, so this is a current topic for me. And that's also why I think ou shouldn't do this.*

Comment: "as efficient as possible" really depends on how you intend on using it. For instance, do you need random access or find-by-key or is begin-to-end iteration sufficient? But without knowing, I would say `std::list` is a decent starting point since it shouldn't change the memory location of its elements when other parts of the list are manipulated.

Comment: " Each chunk has to be able to access each of its 6 neighbour chunks." IMHO I think you should try to change that, this feels like too much of responsibility for a single class.

Comment: *Mateusz might be a good idea, I'm just not so experienced in c++ yet.     *TheUndeadFish if this is right a list might be the solution; I'll try it out!   *Daniel My chunk needs information about it's neighbour everytime a block changes, since the cube faces are adjacend to each other

Answer (score 0):

Having persistant memory location AND dynamic size will not both happen for the same type (at least not any of the `std::` containers).

You three main choices:

1. Limit the number of elements from start (perhaps to a LARGE amount)
2. Store the pointer to objects rather than objects in your storage [that way, the object itself has a fixed address from allocation, even if the location where the pointer is stored changes].
3. Create your own container that allocates "lumps" of storage [of some reasonable, preferrably fixed, size], such as a linked list or vector of lumps, and store data. If the size is big enough [a few thousand elements], then the overhead will be minimal.

Efficiency for any container is really dependent on what operations you are doing - inserting and deleting is not efficient in `std::vector`, but walking across all elements is. Inserting and deleting is good in `std::list`, but walking from element to element involves pointer chasing, which is not very good for efficiency. `std::map` is really efficient for looking up based on some key, and insert/remove is relatively efficient, but walking across all is similar to `std::list`. The `std::unordered_map` is a bit like `std::vector` for insert [when it grows too big, it re-allocates the whole table], but very fast for finding a specific element.

Comment: Thank you! Storing a pointer to the object is in general what I intended to do. So choice 2 sounds best for me. What do you mean with it? When I have a pointer to an object I still have to store it somewhere!? I've already tried storing them in an vector and my unordered_map contained pointers to them but it also gave me a "SIGTRAP" debugger error.

Comment: Yes, but if you allocated the space for it ONCE, it's not going to move, so you can use a `std::vector`, `std::map`, or whatever else to store the pointers, since they are going to be the same value, regardless of WHERE they are stored within the container -> you don't care if that's been allocated again or not.

Comment: Obviously, if you use pointers incorrectly, that's a different matter - that's not what your question is asking tho'.